# Webkit (particularly, Chrome in Windows) and precise font size

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webkit, font-size

I need to increase font size (CSS, pt) smoothly (+0.3pt). But it looks like it changes with a given step (1pt or even more). Is there a way to get it done?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A font size can only be a whole number of pixels... so even if you set the font-size with a decimal the browser casts the invalid font size to something it can use.

A pixel is, by definition, the smallest element that can be displayed (or not displayed) at the current screen resolution. So this chart may be of some use to you when using pt knowing that you cannot display a decimal of a pixel: http://www.getallfix.com/2011/11/convert-empxpt-and-in-css/

Comment: The source of the problem was disabled ClearType. When enabled, increasing seems to be more smoothed. I suppose now, it's the best choice to have no overriding option in CSS, or else the most of sites will shock me with their fonts.

Comment: So, if a user disabled ClearType, it's OK to show him stepped font increasing.